# Is that a valid state of a SKB ? (where skb->user=1 and skb_shinfo(skb)->dataref=0)

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, network-programming, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

The next issue is regarding linux kernel buffers for managing network packets, as known as **sk_buff**.

I read quite a bit about the linux kernel sk_buff structure and API, but there are still some issues I yet don't understand. Here is a situation I've encountered with (please have a look at the code below):

```
while (dirty-- > 0) {
    if (likely(!rx_q->rx_skbuff[entry])) {
        struct sk_buff *skb;

        skb = netdev_alloc_skb_ip_align(priv->dev, bfsize);
        if (unlikely(!skb)) {
            break;
        }

        rx_q->rx_skbuff[entry] = skb;
    }
    /* 
    This section code has been added by me for debugging:
    */
    else {
        int refcount = refcount_read(&(rx_q->rx_skbuff[entry]->users));
        int dataref = (atomic_read(&skb_shinfo(rx_q->rx_skbuff[entry])->dataref) & SKB_DATAREF_MASK);
        if ( (refcount != 1) || (dataref != 1) ) {
            printk("rx_q->rx_skbuff[%d] is DIRTY but not NULL. refcount(%d), dataref(%d)\n", 
                entry, refcount, dataref);
        }
    }
}
```

Sometimes, when the code does enter the else statement it prints the following:

```
rx_q->rx_skbuff[a valid index] is DIRTY but not NULL. refcount(1), dataref(0)
```

**Question:** Is that a valid state of a SKB ? (where `skb->user=1` and `skb_shinfo(skb)->dataref=0`)
My guess is that `skb_shinfo(skb)->dataref=0` has been somehow overwritten, but I need to verify it.

Thanks!! And if someine is interest, here are the tutorials/articles I've read to dig into the sk_buff structure and API (they are not bad at all):

- [Skbuffs - A tutorial](https://people.sissa.it/%7Einno/pubs/skb.pdf)
- [Management of sk_buffs](https://people.cs.clemson.edu/%7Ewestall/853/notes/skbuff.pdf)
- [Linux Networking And Useful Tips for Real-Time Applications](http://amsekharkernel.blogspot.com/2014/08/what-is-skb-in-linux-kernel-what-are.html)